# Estou com problemas para fazer o personagem se movimentar em python com pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

tela = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600),0,32)

personagem = pygame.image.load('./você.png').convert_alpha()

def get_frame_by_gid(gid):
    global personagem
    columns = 4
    width = 100
    height = 100
    space_h = 0
    margin = 0
    top = 0
    space_v = 0
    linha = gid//columns
    coluna = gid % columns
    x = (coluna*(width+ space_h)) + margin
    y = (linha * (height+ space_v)) + top
    quadro = personagem.subsurface(pygame.Rect((x,y),(width,height)))
    return quadro

cima = [4,5,6,7]
baixo = [0,1,2,3]
esquerda = [8,9,10,11]
direita = [12,13,14,15]


parado_cima = [4]
parado_baixo = [0]
parado_esquerda = [8]
parado_direita = [12]
lista_quadro = esquerda

quadro = 0

clk = pygame.time.Clock()
while True:

    tela.fill((0,0,0))
    quadro = quadro + 1
    if quadro >= len(lista_quadro):
        quadro = 0
    gid = lista_quadro[quadro]
    frame = get_frame_by_gid(gid)

    tela.blit(frame,(400,300))
    pygame.display.update()
    clk.tick(8)

    for i in pygame.event.get():
        if i.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exit()

        elif i.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if i.key == pygame. K_LEFT:
                lista_quadro = esquerda
                

            elif i.key == pygame. K_UP:
                lista_quadro = cima
            elif i.key == pygame. K_DOWN:
                lista_quadro = baixo

            elif i.key == pygame. K_RIGHT:
                lista_quadro = direita


        elif i.type == pygame.KEYUP:

            if i.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                lista_quadro = parado_esquerda
            elif i.key == pygame.K_UP:
                lista_quadro = parado_cima
            elif i.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                lista_quadro = parado_baixo

            elif i.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                lista_quadro = parado_direita
```

Comment: Olá - depois faça um tour pelo site - a sua pergunta está com votos negativos por que faltou adicionar algum texto - só com o código e o título da pergunta as vezes fica um problema descobrir como responder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está pegando a imagem dinamicamente, mas está colocando o desenho mesmo sempre na mesma posição (300,400)  na tela principal -

Tem que criar variáveis (x e y, por exemplo), para manter a posição do personagem, e atualizar essas variáveis dentro dos `if` que verificam as teclas, além de escolher a imagem a desenhar.

Você nem contou se o restante está funcionando bem - sem nenhuma mensagem de erro - com um código desse tamanho fica difícil adivinhar se está tudo ok, apesar de parecer. O código parece completo, mas sem a imagem não podemos testar.

Então, se estiver tudo o mais ok, o que podemos fazer: (1) colocar o corpo principal do programa em uma função. Apesar de funcionar assim, com o `while True:` solto no meio do módulo, isso não é recomendável -
fica impossível reutilizar esse código - (por exemplo, quando esse jogo evoluir e você quiser mostrar uma mensagem quando o personagem mudar de tela, e voltar nesse `while True`: não tem como desse jeito. Se estiver numa função, é só chamar a função de novo.

E aí, como todo o restante dos "if" está certinho, é só adicionarmos as variáveis de localização "x" e "y"  e usarmos essas no lugar dos números fixos - o personagem deve passar a andar.

Bom, coloquei uma imagem qualquer aqui e executei o programa - sim, está de fato sem nenhum outro problema.

Então, além das alterações mínimas que sugeri, coloquei mais algumas
coisas já antecipando três ou quatro outros passos - que você enfrentaria a seguir.

O primeiro deles - além de colocar a lógica do jogo dentro de uma função, fiz isso também com a função de inicialização, *e* coloquei alguns valores
críticos do jogo dentro de variáveis. Com o nome em maiúsculas dessas variáveis, pela convenção de estilo elas devem ser tratadas como constantes - isso é, não fico mudando o valor delas depois de dar o valor inicial. Fiz isso com o tamanho da tela, e com o tamanho do personagem:
desta forma, em outros pontos do código em que eu precisei de referência a esses valores, não precisei copiar o número - e aí, se quiser mudar
depois é só mudar o valor uma vez no código.

As demais coisas comento depois do código:

```py
import pygame

LARG, ALT = 800, 600
TAM_PERSONAGEM = 100

def init():
    global tela, personagem
    pygame.init()

    tela = pygame.display.set_mode((LARG, ALT),0,32)
    personagem = pygame.image.load('./você.png').convert_alpha()


def get_frame_by_gid(gid):
    global personagem
    columns = 4
    width = TAM_PERSONAGEM
    height = TAM_PERSONAGEM
    space_h = 0
    margin = 0
    top = 0
    space_v = 0
    linha = gid//columns
    coluna = gid % columns
    x = (coluna*(width+ space_h)) + margin
    y = (linha * (height+ space_v)) + top
    quadro = personagem.subsurface(pygame.Rect((x,y),(width,height)))
    return quadro


cima = [4,5,6,7]
baixo = [0,1,2,3]
esquerda = [8,9,10,11]
direita = [12,13,14,15]


parado_cima = [4]
parado_baixo = [0]
parado_esquerda = [8]
parado_direita = [12]

passo = 20

def principal():
    lista_quadro = parado_esquerda
    quadro = 0
    clk = pygame.time.Clock()

    x_anterior = x = LARG // 2
    y_anterior = y = ALT // 2

    vel_x = vel_y = 0

    while True:

        tela.fill((0,0,0))
        quadro = quadro + 1
        if quadro >= len(lista_quadro):
            quadro = 0
        gid = lista_quadro[quadro]
        frame = get_frame_by_gid(gid)

        pygame.draw.rect(tela, (0, 0, 0),(x_anterior, y_anterior, 100, 100))
        tela.blit(frame,(x, y))
        pygame.display.update()
        clk.tick(8)

        for i in pygame.event.get():
            if i.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return

            elif i.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if i.key == pygame. K_LEFT:
                    lista_quadro = esquerda
                    vel_x = - passo
                elif i.key == pygame. K_UP:
                    lista_quadro = cima
                    vel_y = - passo
                elif i.key == pygame. K_DOWN:
                    lista_quadro = baixo
                    vel_y = passo
                elif i.key == pygame. K_RIGHT:
                    lista_quadro = direita
                    vel_x = passo

            elif i.type == pygame.KEYUP:

                if i.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    lista_quadro = parado_esquerda
                    vel_x = 0
                elif i.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    lista_quadro = parado_cima
                    vel_y = 0
                elif i.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    lista_quadro = parado_baixo
                    vel_y = 0
                elif i.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    lista_quadro = parado_direita
                    vel_x = 0

        x_anterior = x
        y_anterior = y

        if 0 <= x + vel_x < LARG - TAM_PERSONAGEM :
            x += vel_x
        if 0 <= y + vel_y < LARG - TAM_PERSONAGEM :
            y += vel_y

init()
principal()
pygame.quit()
```

Primeira coisa - além de introduzir o "x" e "y", introduzi "vel_x" e "vel_y" - para indicar quantos pixels andar em cada eixo - e atualizar tudo no final. Eu poderia fazer só

```
...
   if i.key == pygame. K_LEFT:
      lista_quadro = esquerda
       x -= passo
...
```

Isso é - somar minha variável de passo direto no x e no y - mas tendo uma variável de "velocidade x" eu ganho duas coisas: primeiro - os PCs enviam sim vários eventos de 'KEYDOWN' nquanto uma tecla estiver pressionada - mas a quantidade de eventos depende de parâmetros de repetição de teclas do sistema operacional -você poderia receber menos de um 'KEYDOWN' (ou mais de um) em cada frame do jogo - e aí a movimentação no eixo x iria ficar irregular. Com a velocidade, eu falo que ele está andando pra esquerda no primeiro evento de keydown - e pronto, só vai parar quando houver um "KEYUP" da tecla-seta correspondente, e a velocidade for pra zero.

A segunda vantagem tem a ver com um dos avanços que fiz no jogo - no final da função, antes de atualizaro x  e y em cada quadro, verifico se o persongaem vai continuar nos limites da tela. (use a forma `0 < x < max` que é característica do Python, funciona como a notação aprendemos em matemática. Internamente o Python faz o mesmo que  `0 < x and x < max`) -
se não tivesse um vel_x - eu teria que fazer essa verificação na tecla pra esquerda e na tecla pra direita: muito mais linhas de programa,e mistura de conceitos - pegar o evento, com "verificar se o persongem pode" . Com o codigo de verificação separado, fica fácil quando o projeto crescer passar isso pra uma função a parte também.

Bom, e além do vel_x e vel_y eu peguei ai um `x_anterior` e `y_anterior` - por que se o programa simplesmetne desenhasse o personagem na nova posição, a posição anterior ficaria marcada e ele iria deixando "rastro". Hmm . mas só agora notei que também é feita uma chamada a `tela.fill` - isso limpa a tela entre um frame e outro - só que usa muito mais processamento da máquina - com o x e y anterior e desenhando o retangulo preto na posição anterior, não é necessário preencher a tela toda .

A recomendação é você experimentar aí - até entender esses pontos todos - experiemnte tirar a chamada a "tela.fill" e comentar também o `pygame.draw.rect` - e vai ver o rastro deixado - é importante para entender o funcionamento do jogo e do programa, num nível em que quem programa para um engine de jogo pronto, simplesmente não entende - esses conceitos ficam faltando.

Bom projeto aí - nas próximas perguntas, não esqueça de dar um pouco de contexto, senão o pessoal fecha a pergunta antes de alguém conseguir responder. (peguei aqui com 4 votos pra fechar - no 5º voto ela é fechada)

Comment: Muito obrigada pela sua ajuda, a  faculdade pede todo semestre  como trabalho de integração de todas as matérias que a gente se reuna em grupos e crie jogos, geralmente eu me concentro só em cuidar das animações, mas o professor exigiu que todos do grupo teriam que ter uma boa noção da programação, então eu estou tentando correr atras disso.

Comment: legal - espero que ter ajudado. Pra mim seria legal se você mostrasse essa resposta para os outros integrates do grupo também - acho que deu pra agregar bastante valor nela.